# Which is correct: "no issues", "not an issue", "some issues", or "some issue"?

Tags: grammar, countability

Is the noun "issue" used in singular form, or is it fine to use it in plural form? 
example:

1. no issues.
2. not an issue.
3. I had been facing some issues in the past which now are resolved.
4. I had been facing some issue in the past which now are resolved.

Which one is correct?

Comment: As [OALD would tell you](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/issue_1), *issue* in the sense of "problem" is countable, but in several of its other meanings, it is not.

Answer (score 3):

In that sense it is countable (*an issue*, *some issues*), so of your examples 1, 2 and 3 would be correct while 4 should be changed to "an issue".

In the sense meaning "children or offspring" it is used as a mass noun, so "the marriage produced no issue" or "This marriage produced issue, who split the estate between them".

Comment: Also, in #4 the verb "are" would be changed to "is" to match the singular form of issue.